# RESTEasy support for JAX-RS @RolesAllowed

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I've spend hours installing a custom login service in embedded Jetty 9.1.0.v20131115 and RESTEasy 3.0.5.Final. My login service will look users up in a database and assign them roles. It looks something like this:

```
final Constraint restConstraint = new Constraint();
restConstraint.setName(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH);
restConstraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user", "admin");
restConstraint.setAuthenticate(true);
final ConstraintMapping restConstraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
restConstraintMapping.setConstraint(restConstraint);
restConstraintMapping.setPathSpec("/api/*");
final ConstraintSecurityHandler restSecurityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
final LoginService myLoginService = new MyLoginService();
restSecurityHandler.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
restSecurityHandler.setRealmName(myLoginService.getName());
restSecurityHandler.addConstraintMapping(restConstraintMapping);
restSecurityHandler.setLoginService(myLoginService);
```

I have users `joe-user` who has the role of `user`, and `jane-admin` who has both `user` and `admin` roles. I have a REST `GET` resource named `my-resource` marked with:

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
```

When I do an HTTP `GET` on `my-resource`, the browser correctly requests credentials, and I can login as either `joe-user` or `jane-admin`. The problem is that either user is allowed to `GET` `my-resource`!!

I've traced through some of the Jetty code, and indeed, as a result of my login service above, Jetty asks the login user which roles is supported. Unfortunately, Jetty will accept *any* of the roles I've specified in `restConstraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user", "admin")`, regardless of the user.

Apparently it is the RESTEasy layer that is supposed to recognize the `@RolesAllowed("admin")` annotation and validate the user. But how do I get RESTEasy to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a little help from the [RESTEasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.5.Final/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html), I found out that in order for RESTEasy to honor the `@RolesAllowed` annotations, one must turn on the `resteasy.role.based.security` context parameter switch in the `web.xml` file; or programatically, as I am doing:

```
final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new HttpServlet30Dispatcher());
servletHolder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", MyApplication.class.getName());
servletHolder.setInitParameter("resteasy.role.based.security", String.valueOf(true));
contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/*");
```

Comment: When you do not have a web.xml where would you put the code you posted in order to set it programmatically?

Comment: I don't have the code with me, but from reading my original question it appears I was using Jetty. You'll have to look at the documentation for embedding Jetty—then my code should make more sense.